# Pri Chadash and Coffee

Tags: rabbis

I have read that the Pri Chadash writes somewhere that “one cannot attain presence of mind without the aid of coffee.”?

Does anyone know where this was written?

Comment: FWIW the chronology works out, if this quote does exist. Coffee would have been in Italy for about sixty years by the time Rav de Silva was born.

Answer (score 13):

Beer Heitev to [Orach Chayim 89:3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%98_%D7%92) (ד״ה מותר) quotes the Pri Chadash saying:

> Coffee can be drunk (before prayer), particularly in Egypt where their thinking doesn't work properly without coffee.
>
> וכ"כ הפר"ח דקאו"י יכול לשתות ובפרט במצרים **שאין הדעת מתיישב בלא קאו"י** אבל קאו"י עם צו"קר או כל מיני תרגומא כדי שלא לשתות הקאו"י אליבא ריקנא אסור ע"ש